# Error in JSF/CDI conversation scope when begin is called two times

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, conversation-scope

I'm using the CDI conversation scope and it's ok when user follows the normal scenario. However, when user don't complete de "conversation" I get this error:

```
WELD-000214 Attempt to call begin() on a long-running conversation
```

Obviously, is because there are 2 calls to the *begin* method without calling the *end* method.

To clarify it this is my scenario:

- In the first page the user search for a product by a reference
  number. If it's found I call the *conversation.begin* and navigate to
  the product details page.
- In this page when the user push save button
  and in this point I call the *conversation.end*.

The problem is when being in the details page the user leaves out (for instance, clicking an link in the menu), so the *end* method is not called. And when their return to the search page I get the error because *begin* is called again.

I think, one possible solution may be to call the *end* method when user exists the second page. But I don't know how to achieve this.

(I'm using JSF 2.1, and Weld 1.1.6 implementation of CDI)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is intentional. You can easily check `conversation.isTransient()` to decide whether you want to  / need to make a conversation long-running.

> If begin() is called, and the current conversation is already marked
>   long-running, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

([see the spec here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/contexts.html#d0e5678))

Answer (score 2):

Always begin conversation checking first is conversation ended using isTransient() method.

```
public void beginConversation(){
    if (!conversation.isTransient()){
        conversation.end();
    }
    conversation.begin();
}
```